# When are 2 single quote marks interpreted as a double quote mark?

Tags: text, character-encoding

Is there any common programming language or text interface where two single quotes are interpreted as a double quote?

Comment: Only by your eyeballs...?

Comment: Needs much more context. As it is, valid answers are "never", "always", and pretty much everything in between.

Comment: @macsplean: no. You'll need to specify _one_ language.

Comment: @Mat - I intentionally left out a language because I was curious about the context of computer programming languages in general. This is a fairly general question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When are 2 single quote marks interpreted as a double quote mark?

*Never*, period

Some language might offer you the functionality to use two single quotes instead of one double quote to achieve the same purpose but it will know *exactly* that those are two single quotes, and it will not `interpret` them as a double quote still.